# Column value is read as date instead of string - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an excel file and in that one row of column `Model` is having value "9-3" which is a string value. I double-checked the excel file to have the column datatype as Plain string instead of Date. But still When I use read_excel and convert it into a data frame, the value is shown as 2017-09-03 00:00:00 instead of string "9-3". 
Here is how I read the excel file:

```
  table = pd.read_excel('ManualProfitAdjustmentUpdates.xlsx' , header=0, converters={'Model': str})
```

Any idea on why pandas is not treating value as string even when I set the converters as str?

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the Excel file - ideally the column headers and the first row of data. If the data is private, then just the header row would be OK.

Comment: (Reason for comment is to replicate, but also to check whether the "converters" definition is defined correctly).

Answer (score 2):

The Plain string setting in the excel file affects only how the data is shown in Excel.
The str setting in the converter affects only how it treats the data that it gets.

To force the excel file to return the data as string, the cell's first character should be an apostrophe.
Change "9-3" to "'9-3".

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be with excel. Make sure the entire column is stored as text and not just the singular value you are talking about. If excel had the column saved as a data at any point it will store a year in that cell no matter what is shown or what the datatype is changed too. Pandas is going to read the entire column as one data type so if you have dates above 9-3 it will be converted. Changing dates to strings without years can be tricky. It may be better to save the excel sheet as a csv once it is in the proper format you like and then use pandas pd.read_csv(). I made a test excel workbook "book1.xlsx"

```
9-3    1  Hello
12-1   2  World
1-8    3  Test
```

Then ran

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx',header=0)
print(df)
```

and got back my data frame correctly. Thus, I am led to believe it is excel. Sorry is isn't the best answer but I don't believe it is a pandas error.